# How to send ps file to printer spool to avoid out of paper issue and so on

Tags: c#

I have try a sample like below but fail, I want using system.printing. In before, i was using TCP and send to printer. but somehow, the printer will run of toner, run of paper, and so on. so It will came out exception after tcp fail. it became print fail. so i hope i can add printing job into printer spool to avoid the issue

here the reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue.addjob?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Printing;

namespace WindowFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.detail();
        }
        private void detail()
        {
            getSystemPrinters();
        }
        private void getSystemPrinters()
        {
            // Create a new local print server
        
            LocalPrintServer printServer = new LocalPrintServer();

            // Select a printer from the available print queues
            PrintQueue selectedPrintQueue = SelectPrintQueue(printServer.GetPrintQueues());

            if (selectedPrintQueue != null )
            {
                SpotTroubleUsingProperties(out String statusReport, selectedPrintQueue);
                if (statusReport == null)
                {
                    // Print a PS file
                    PrintPSFile(selectedPrintQueue, @"C:\dhl_digi\\RawPrintServer\Spool\Fail\1.ps");
                    //PrintPSFile(selectedPrintQueue, @"C:\dhl_digi\DocGateway\GF_OCR_PDF\1.xps");
                }
                else
                {
                    //handle printer error
                }
               
            }

            // Dispose the print server
            printServer.Dispose();
        }

        // Select a print queue from the available print queues
        public static PrintQueue SelectPrintQueue(PrintQueueCollection printQueues)
        {
            // Create a dialog to select a printer
            PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();

            // Set the available print queues
            printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = null; // Set the initial printer name if desired
            foreach (PrintQueue printQueue in printQueues)
            {
                if (printQueue.FullName.Equals("CI PRINTER"))
                {
                    // printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printQueue.FullName;
                    //String selectedPrinter = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
                    return printQueue;
                }
             
            }

            return null; // No printer selected
        }

        // Print a PS file to the specified print queue
        public static void PrintPSFile(PrintQueue pq, string psFilePath)
        {

            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(psFilePath);
            string fullname = f.FullName;

            byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(fullname);



            using (var job = pq.AddJob())
            using (var stream = job.JobStream)
            {
                stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
            }



        }



        // Check for possible trouble states of a printer using its properties
        public static void SpotTroubleUsingProperties(out String statusReport, PrintQueue pq)
        {
            statusReport = null;
            if (pq.HasPaperProblem)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport+ "Has a paper problem. ";
            }
            if (!(pq.HasToner))
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Is out of toner. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsDoorOpened)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Has an open door. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsInError)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Is in an error state. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsNotAvailable)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Is not available. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsOffline)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Is off line. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsOutOfMemory)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Is out of memory. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsOutOfPaper)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Is out of paper. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsOutputBinFull)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Has a full output bin. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsPaperJammed)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Has a paper jam. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsPaused)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Is paused. ";
            }
            if (pq.IsTonerLow)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Is low on toner. ";
            }
            if (pq.NeedUserIntervention)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Needs user intervention. ";
            }

          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what fails. Do you get an exception?

Comment: hi palle due , i have no receive any exception after send file to printer. but no file was printed

Comment: even printer out of paper or door open, it detect printer in good condition